# Extract several pages from a djvu file

Tags: text-processing, djvu

I have a djvu file of multiple pages. I wonder how to extract a new djvu file that consists of only a subset of multiple pages?

For example, a djvu file has 10 pages, and I would like to extract a new djvu file consisting of pages 3-6 of the original djvu file. Can it be done with some commands of djvulibre, such as djvused, djvm, ...? I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Consider two different cases: extract without removal of pages from the original djvu file, and extract without removal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I didn't see any way to explicitly save a range of pages, so I opted to delete the rest.

```
# Extract and save each page in its own file
pages=$(djvused -e 'n' "$if")
for ((i=1; i<=$pages; i++)) ;do
    of="${if%.*}.$(printf "%03d" $i).djvu"
    djvused -e "select $i; save-page-with \"$of\"" "$if"
done
```

---

```
# Remove one page from an existing djvu file
djvm -delete "$if" 2 # remove page 2
```

---

```
# Save pages 3-6 to a new file, by removing 
#   all other pages from a copy of the original
from=3; to=6
of="${if%.*}.$from-$to.djvu"
cp "$if" "$of"  
pages=$(djvused -e 'n' "$of")
for ((i=$pages; i>$to; i--)) ;do  djvm -delete "$of" $i ;done
for ((i=1;    i<$from; i++)) ;do  djvm -delete "$of" 1  ;done
```

Comment: I cannot believe that this still seems to be the way to go. But after looking around a bit, this seems to be the way. I would be happy to be shown wrong, though.

Answer (score 6):

I would just use: [DjVuLibre DjView 4.5](http://djvulibre.djvuzone.org) Viewer for DjVu documents. Its GUI has a *Save as* function under *File* menu and there one can save a given range of pages into djvu file.

Comment: How is djview possible to extract multiple pages from a djvu file?

Comment: it has a feature to only consider a page range in both "export" and "save as" File menu items, as specified; wonder why you didn't accept a perfectly good answer

Answer (score 1):

A simpler series of shell statements to achieve bundled DjVU splitting:

```
mkdir -- 'mydoc/' &&
djvmcvt -i 'mydoc.djvu' 'mydoc/' 'new-mydoc-index.djvu'
```